# Status "this year" questions

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

[2008: Resharper vs. CodeRush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216/2008-resharper-vs-coderush)
This Question has 63 votes and 18 answers, the top answer has 74 votes. It contains a useful comparison of two competing products and is pretty even-handed.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693354/2011-resharper-vs-coderush
This question is closed as "not constructive".

What's the deal here? This seems like a useful and valuable question in general, and, as both products are evolving, it seems fair to ask for a re-evaluation after 3 years.

Comment: Try reposting on programmer.se

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765841/resharper-vs-coderush-2010-remake that has not been closed

Comment: @Ian - please don't suggest that. The new question is no more constructive on Programmers than it is on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Chris, but that sort of quesion does not get closed as often on Programmers

Comment: @Ian - The question *as phrased* is not constructive. If there are other questions like that on Programmers please flag them and we'll take a look. If the question was worded differently then it *might* be OK.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about.  The first one is closed as well.

Comment: This question is a good example of why those questions should be removed. People will continue to point to them and ask why *they* can't ask subjective questions if someone else did.

Comment: @won't - maybe you'd like to not know what Ian is talking about as well?

Comment: @bemace: I'd be happy to start with knowing what the heck *you're* talking about.

Comment: @wont - hmm... well played indeed

Answer (score 10):

The deal is that what was acceptable when StackOverflow opened is no longer acceptable now.

And, before anybody tries, you cannot still hang horse thieves once you catch them.  You must turn them over to the authorities.

Comment: I live in Texas. That law is actually still on the books in some small towns. And it's a capital offense once you *do* turn them over to the authorities.

Answer (score 6):

The best explanation is from the close reason itself

> We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

I think in the past, the site was more accepting of less concrete questions like the 2008 version, but I think the current consensus is that opinion-type questions cannot have one correct answer, and so are considered subjective.

Questions considering X product in 20YY could also technically be considered too localized, as the nature of the products could go off in drastically different directions over time.

Answer (score 4):

There is a concrete question in 2008-year question:

> At which areas do you think is Resharper better and at which areas CodeRush?

And that is why old question is good (for that time).

At 2011-year question we see:

> Or are there any good free refactoring tools. Please recommend which refactoring tool is best.

There is no question - only topic for discussion. If question will be refactored, I think, it will be re-open.

Comment: And even that concrete question is... kinda weak.

Comment: Too weak, too localized, not a good fit anymore.

Comment: @Won't♦ Updated the answer.